# DBCC CHECKDB to check errors in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbcc

Is it possible to run: `DBCC CHECKDB` on a specific table in SQL Server 2005 database?

I have the following syntax:

```
DBCC CHECKDB 
[
    [ ( database_name | database_id | 0
        [ , NOINDEX 
        | , { REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD } ]
    ) ]
    [ WITH 
        {
            [ ALL_ERRORMSGS ]
            [ , EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS ] 
            [ , NO_INFOMSGS ]
            [ , TABLOCK ]
            [ , ESTIMATEONLY ]
            [ , { PHYSICAL_ONLY | DATA_PURITY } ]
        }
    ]
]
```

But keep getting incorrect syntax. I just want to run it to see what errors it throws up? Can you help me with writing the syntax? I want to remove all repair options.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DBCC CHECKDB` as it names apply is for checking databases.

There is a [`DBCC CHECKTABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174338.aspx) command for checking specific tables. Usage is:

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE ('YourTable');
```

Comment: I have just ran, `DBCC CHECKDB(AdventureWorks2008R2)` that wont repair anything will it???????????? !!

Comment: DBCC CHECKTABLE ('YourTable',REPAIR_REBUILD)

Comment: Hi, I just stumble to this post after searching for answers with my problem on the table of my db with logical consistency. my question does dbcc checktable(yourtable, REPAIR_REBUILD) can repair this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but, oh, well...  See [MS DBCC CHECKTABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checktable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Syntax:
    `DBCC CHECKTABLE ( table_name | view_name
        [ , { NOINDEX | index_id }
         |, { REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS | REPAIR_FAST | REPAIR_REBUILD } ] )
        [ WITH
            { [ ALL_ERRORMSGS ]
              [ , EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS ]
              [ , NO_INFOMSGS ]
              [ , TABLOCK ]
              [ , ESTIMATEONLY ]
              [ , { PHYSICAL_ONLY | DATA_PURITY } ]
              [ , MAXDOP = number_of_processors ]
            }
        ]`

Be careful using any of the REPAIR options.  Note that the ESTIMATEONLY Argument is just that and ZERO impact, and the PHYSICAL_ONLY option may have a much shorter run-time on large tables.